# How can I improve the compiler's handling of my SSE intrinsics?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, sse

Having read [this interesting article on the results of intrinsic-guided optimization of SSE code in different C++ compilers](http://www.liranuna.com/sse-intrinsics-optimizations-in-popular-compilers/) I decided to do a test of my own, especially since the post is a few years old. I used MSVC which did so very poorly in the tests performed by the author of the post (although in the VS 2010 version) and decided to stick to a very basic scenario: packing some values into a XMM register and doing a simple operation like addition. In the article, _mm_set_ps translated into a weird sequence of scalar move and unpack instructions, so let's see:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __m128 foo = _mm_set_ps(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
    __m128 bar = _mm_set_ps(5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f);
    __m128 ret = _mm_add_ps(foo, bar);

    // need to do something so vars won't be optimized out in Release
    float *f = (float *)(&ret);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        cout << "f[" << i << "] = " << f[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Next, I compiled and ran this inside the debugger, looking at the disassembly:

**Debug:**

> __m128 foo = _mm_set_ps(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
>   00B814F0  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr ds:[0B87840h]
>   00B814F7  movaps      xmmword ptr [ebp-190h],xmm0
>   00B814FE  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp-190h]
>   00B81505  movaps      xmmword ptr [foo],xmm0
>     __m128 bar = _mm_set_ps(5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f);
>   00B81509  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr ds:[0B87850h]
>   00B81510  movaps      xmmword ptr [ebp-170h],xmm0
>   00B81517  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp-170h]
>   00B8151E  movaps      xmmword ptr [bar],xmm0
>     __m128 ret = _mm_add_ps(foo, bar);
>   00B81522  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [bar]
>   00B81526  movaps      xmm1,xmmword ptr [foo]
>   00B8152A  addps       xmm1,xmm0
>   00B8152D  movaps      xmmword ptr [ebp-150h],xmm1
>   00B81534  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp-150h]
>   00B8153B  movaps      xmmword ptr [ret],xmm0

Utterly confused; why does putting a xmmword into a __m128 require four MOVAPS? First, it puts the data into xmm0 (I assume it's the literal for the four float values stored somewhere, not sure how to look at it), then copies xmm0 somewhere pointed to by ebp and an offset, only to copy it back again from there to xmm0 (?), and finally to the location of the variable that's supposed to store it. Why so much work?

**Release:**
This time I was expecting the compiler to avoid storing xmmword's in memory at all, just put one in xmm0, other in xmm1, do an ADDPS, put result in memory and be done with it. Instead I got:

> __m128 foo = _mm_set_ps(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
>     __m128 bar = _mm_set_ps(5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f);
>     __m128 ret = _mm_add_ps(foo, bar);
>   003E1009  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr ds:[3E2130h]
>   003E1010  push        esi
>   003E1011  movaps      xmmword ptr [esp+10h],xmm0

Apparently, no need for ADDPS. I'm guessing the compiler noticed the two xmmwords were compile-time constants so it just added them, putting the result in the code as a literal? The odd push has probably to do with the for-loop that follows, because esi is used as a loop counter there as far as I can tell. Still, why put the precalculated literal from the data segment into xmm0 and then into a local variable (esp+10h), why not just use the literal directly?

To sum up, the Debug version was more stupid than I expected (or maybe I'm not getting something), while the Release version was unexpectedly clever. Any comments explaining this behaviour would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** The answers were very enlightening, but I still would like to know if there's anything **I** can do to improve the compiler output, which is why I am changing the question from asking for explanation of this to the current form.

For example, would it be possible to somehow guide the compiler to not store *foo* and *bar* in memory (since I don't need them after the addition), just load them into xmmN registers and keep them there? Possibly *ret* too? The author of the cited article said MSVC was just "doing exactly what it was told to". Any way to get better (read: avoiding memory transfers) code without explicitly writing an __asm block? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a normal side effect of the way the code generator works.  The _mm_set_ps() has **two** distinct jobs to do.  It first must built up the __m128 value from the 4 arguments.  You picked the easy way, it gets a lot more convoluted with:

```
float x = 1.0f;
__m128 foo = _mm_set_ps(x, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
```

With drastically different codegen:

```
00C513DD  movss       xmm0,dword ptr ds:[0C5585Ch]  
00C513E5  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [x]  
00C513EA  movaps      xmm2,xmmword ptr ds:[0C55860h]  
00C513F1  unpcklps    xmm0,xmm1  
00C513F4  unpcklps    xmm2,xmm0  
00C513F7  movaps      xmmword ptr [ebp-100h],xmm2
```

The second job is then to move it into the __m128 variable, that's easy

```
00C513FE  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp-100h]  
00C51405  movaps      xmmword ptr [foo],xmm0
```

That this isn't optimized yet is simply because the optimizer is turned off in the Debug build.  The code generator doesn't make any attempt to optimize, that's just not its job.

And sure, the optimizer was capable of calculating the result at compile time.  That even works for the convoluted example, you've already seen this:

```
00EE1284  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr ds:[0EE3260h]
```

Comment: Thanks @Hans, would you also kindly address the edit on Q? Thank you.

Comment: There's just no point in doing anything to improve it.  Just build the Release version of your project and you're done.  Turning on the optimizer in the debug build just makes debugging a lot harder, the point of a debug build is to make it *easier*.  You can if you really want to, helps to get insight in how hard it gets.

Comment: Okay, but say if the input was not compile-constant: anything to avoid in the SSE code so that the compiler is free to optimize? @Søren mentioned not taking addresses of __m128's. Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the compile-time optimization for the release build (look up `ds:[3E2130h]` in your object file and you will find the added values there).

Yes, the debug version seems to do unnecessary work, but only by a factor of 2, not a factor of 4. One would actually expect that

```
 movaps xmmword ptr [foo],xmmword ptr ds:[0B87840h]
```

existed, but it doesn't, `MOVAPS` comes in two variants, and neither allows moving from memory to memory (this is the usual case in x86):

```
MOVAPS xmm1,xmm2/mem128       ; 0F 28 /r        [KATMAI,SSE]
MOVAPS xmm1/mem128,xmm2       ; 0F 29 /r        [KATMAI,SSE]
```

What the debug assembly does is read the xmmword from `ds:[0B87840h]` in the `.data` section of your object file (which is most likely readonly), and puts it on the stack at `[ebp-190h]` as well as in `foo`.

For comparison, gcc 4.7 exhibits a similar pattern:

```
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip] # D.5374,
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-64], xmm0  # foo, D.5353
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip] # D.5381,
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-48], xmm0  # bar, D.5354
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-64]  # tmp79, foo
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-32], xmm0  # __A, tmp79
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-48]  # tmp80, bar
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-16], xmm0  # __B, tmp80
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-16]  # tmp81, __B
movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-32]  # tmp82, __A
addps   xmm0, xmm1  # D.5386, tmp82
```

I would assume that this has to do with the way that the builtin intrinsics are implemented.  For example, `_mm_add_ps` works with `__m128` arguments that may be in registers, on the stack or somewhere else at the time when it is called. Therefore, if you're writing the intrinsics code for gcc/VC++, you have to generate code first that will load the values. When the optimizer runs, it immediately notices that there is unnecessary pushing around of data (but the optimizer does not run in debug builds).

Comment: wrt. to "one would expect `movaps [mem], [mem]` existed ..." - no. This type of instruction, direct memory-memory copy, doesn't exist in x86 anywhere other than in string moves (`rep movs`). All other instructions in x86 (and that includes all SSE/AVX) can only ever have _a single_ memory operand.

Comment: @FrankH. That's exactly what I said, if you read on: "(this is the usual case in x86)". Still, if you are fairly new to assembler, it's not unreasonable to expect that there *are* [mem],[mem] instructions, it is a common source of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question about MSVC internals. To get a definite answer, you'd have to ask Microsoft.

One might speculate that the reason the Release build puts ret into a local variable is that you have taken its address. Taking the address of a variable means the compiler suddenly has to deal with *memory* rather than registers. Memory is much harder for a compiler because other places in the program may have pointers to that the optimizer must account for.